# Filter multiple arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following situation:

There are an undefined number of arrays. Each array contains some objects. Each of these objects has an `id` element, among some other elements.

```
//Example objects:

f = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'd'}, ...]
g = [{'id': 2, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}, 
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'g'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'h'}, ...]
h = ...
i = ...
```

I would like to filter out all the duplicates, not only inside every separate array, but also across the different arrays.

**Edit:** Two objects are a duplicate when their `id` element are the same. Precedence does not matter, first occurrence is fine for this.

I came up with the following function:

```
function uniqueObjects() {
    var seen = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        for (var j=0; j<arg.length; j++) {
            var elm = arg[j];
            var key = elm['id'];
            if (seen.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                arg.pop(elm);
            } else {
                seen.push(key);
            }
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

But this does not seem to work properly, since I got the following values:

```
{'0': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, 
       {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}, 
       {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}], 
 '1': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'e'}, 
       {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]}
```

Comment: can you put this in a fiddle.

Comment: How do you define a "duplicate"? same `id` or same all properties?

Comment: And how do you want to filter out the duplicates, what gives presidence: Does the first occurrence of an id matter more than the last? Is it dependent on the value of name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
arg.pop(elm);
```

`pop` removes the **last** element in the array and doesn't take any arguments. You may have meant:

```
arg.splice(j, 1);
```

...but then you need to **not** increment `j` if you do that. So that gives us:

```
function uniqueObjects() {
    var seen = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        var j = 0;                       // **
        while (j<arg.length) {           // ** Made this a while loop
            var elm = arg[j];
            var key = elm['id'];
            if (seen.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                arg.splice(j, 1);         // ** Remove this entry
            } else {
                seen.push(key);
                ++j;                      // ** Increment j
            }
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

**However**, there is a much more efficient way to track which `id` values you've seen: Using an object:

```
function uniqueObjects() {
    var seen = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        var j = 0;
        while (j<arg.length) {
            var elm = arg[j];
            var key = " " + elm['id'];    // ** Note the space
            if (seen[key]) {              // ** Updated check
                arg.splice(j, 1);
            } else {
                seen[key] = true;         // ** Set the flag
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

Why put the space before the `id` when creating `key`? On the *off-chance* that you have `id` values with names that exist on objects, like `toString` or `valueOf`. (ES6 will introduce `Map` objects and we won't have to do that anymore.)

I'd also recommend *not* returning the pseudo-array `arguments`, but instead using a *real* array. So:

```
function uniqueObjects() {
    var seen = {};
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); // <== Make real array
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        var arg = args[i];
        var j = 0;
        while (j<arg.length) {
            var elm = arg[j];
            var key = " " + elm['id'];    // ** Note the space
            if (seen[key]) {              // ** Updated check
                arg.splice(j, 1);
            } else {
                seen[key] = true;         // ** Set the flag
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
    return args;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function uniqueObjects() {
    var seen = {};
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
        var arg = args[i];
        var j = 0;
        while (j<arg.length) {
            var elm = arg[j];
            var key = " " + elm['id'];    // ** Note the space
            if (seen[key]) {              // ** Updated check
                arg.splice(j, 1);
            } else {
                seen[key] = true;         // ** Set the flag
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
    return args;
}

var f = [
  {'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'},
  {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'd'}
];
var g = [
  {'id': 2, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'},
  {'id': 3, 'name': 'g'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'h'}
];
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify([f, g]));
var result = uniqueObjects(f, g);
snippet.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```